# Load a key value file to a map in scala then load the values to a vector

Tags: arrays, scala, vector

New to scala. I have a key value file containing

```
    key1=value1~value2 
    key2=value3~value4~value5
    key3=value7~value8
```

I want to load it to a map from a file.
I want to find and match if I receive key1 or key2 at run time.
Then store the corresponding values (separated by ~) to a vector.
So that I can do foreach on the vector and perform different things based on the value.

Comment: What do you by a vector? Should line 2 be List("", "", "value3", "value4", "value5") or List("value3", "value4", "value5")? Could you provide as well what you've already tried?

Comment: Please post what the resulting `Vector` should look like (i.e. its contents) along with whatever code you've tried so far.

Comment: This is how I dealt with the situation 

    val readFile = scala.io.Source.fromFile(Path+"/test.txt").getLines.map(line => {
           val tokens = line.split("""\=+""") // Use a regex to avoid empty tokens. Splitting file to 2 column and then a list
           (tokens(0), tokens(1))
        }).toList
    val matchKey = readMapingFile.filter(_._1==Keys.trim())
    val pickMatchedKV = matchKey(0)  // I don't have duplicate keys in my case
    val value = pickMatchedKV._2
    val spiltValuestoArray = value.split("~")

    spiltValuestoArray.foreach(println)
  passed keys via Keys

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have  file `test.txt` which contains:

```
key1=value1~value2 
key2=value3~value4~value5
key3=value7~value8
```

Below code will parse and create List of `Tuple` with key and related to it `List` (it could be easily convert to `Map` -> just invoke `toMap`):

```
val filename = "test.txt"

val result = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines
  .map(line => {
    line.split("=") match {
      case Array(a, b) => (a, b.split("~").toList)
    }
  }).toList

println(result)
```

The result would be:

```
List((key1,List(value1, value2)), (key2,List(value3, value4, value5)), (key3,List(value7, value8)))
```

If you want `Map` you need just invoke `toMap`:
`println(result.toMap)`
Result for that would be:

```
Map(key1 -> List(value1, value2), key2 -> List(value3, value4, value5), key3 -> List(value7, value8))
```

Comment: @Sat Glad I could help. If it is helpful please mark it (by voting) :)

Comment: I am unable to vote it up as I don't have enough reputation.I am a newbie here. I think there is a way that you can ask me to accept the answer. And that way I can accept it.

Comment: @Sat Hmm, I guess you can do it now. You can vote up above 15.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, though it might not be the ideal solution, though it will give you the desired output:

Read lines from the file

`val list = Source.fromFile("path").getLines().toList`

then do the following:

```
  val outPutList = list.map { data =>
 val splittedList =  data.split("=").toList
  val listOfTupple =(splittedList.head,splittedList.tail.mkString.split("~").toList)
  listOfTupple
}

outPutList.toMap
```

Expected Output:

```
 Map(key1 -> List(value1, value2), key2 -> List(value3, value4,value5))
```

Iterate over the values to perform the desired action.